# General grok pattern

Tags: regex, logstash, elastic-stack, regex-group, logstash-grok

This is my logs:

```
<85>May 8 11:26:40 test123 sudo: LCOpsMGRSCX : (command blablalblablalblalba) asdasldma
<85>May 7 20:52:15 test123 sudo[4077568]: program : TTY=pts/0 ;
```

This is my grok pattern:

```
<%{NUMBER:syslogpri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:syslog_device_hostname} %{NOTSPACE:program1}(?:\[%{NUMBER:program_number}\])?:%{GREEDYDATA}
```

And this is the current output:

```
[
  {
    "syslogpri": 85,
    "timestamp": "May 8 11:26:40",
    "syslog_device_hostname": "test123",
    "program1": "sudo"
  },
  {
    "syslogpri": 85,
    "timestamp": "May 7 20:52:15",
    "syslog_device_hostname": "test123",
    "program1": "sudo[4077568]"
  }
]
```

What I want to do is get rid of the number in square brackets from `sudo` in field `program1`.
I am not quite getting regex non-capturing group concept, because I wanted to make this number optional, but it still appears in the output no matter what.
Desired output:

```
[
  {
    "syslogpri": 85,
    "timestamp": "May 8 11:26:40",
    "syslog_device_hostname": "test123",
    "program1": "sudo"
  },
  {
    "syslogpri": 85,
    "timestamp": "May 7 20:52:15",
    "syslog_device_hostname": "test123",
    "program1": "sudo"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `(?<program1>[^\s\[\]]+)` instead of `%{NOTSPACE:program1}`:

```
<%{NUMBER:syslogpri}>%{SYSLOGTIMESTAMP:timestamp} %{NOTSPACE:syslog_device_hostname} %{NOTSPACE:program1}(?:\[%{NUMBER:program_number}\])?:%{GREEDYDATA}
```

See [how this regex works](https://regex101.com/r/vbKHZ5/1) under the hood.

The `(?<program1>[^\s\[\]]+)` is a named capturing group with the `program1` name (`(?<program1>...)`) that matches one or more (`+`) chars other than (`[^...]` is a [negated character class](https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html#negated)) whitespace (`\s`), `[` and `]`.

Comment: It looks better, but it includes semicolon as a field value and does not work with further grok pattern.

Comment: @h0llym0lly It does not match any semi-colon. What is further in your code is not known to us, so we cannot help with that. Please make it clear what you need.

Comment: Basically i posted exactly the examples which are in the interest of mine.
Provided regex includes semicolon as "program1" field value instead of ignoring it.
So value for this field from output one from my example looks like:
`program1: sudo:`

Comment: @h0llym0lly https://regex101.com/r/vbKHZ5/1 shows it does not match any colon. If you think it is the pattern to blame and you do not want it to match `:`, just add it to the negated character class, `(?<program1>[^\s\[\]:]+)`